# Can we have two iCloud accounts on our iPad?

Tags: icloud

I want to access my iCloud account (mail and calendar) on our family iPad. It is currently set up with my husband's iCloud acct. Can we have two accounts on this device?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up multiple iCloud accounts, however, quoting iOS:

> Only your main account can use Photo Stream, Documents & Data, and Backup.
>   [image]

If you want to use mail and calendar only, there is no problem. You can even use all of the other services like contacts, reminders or notes.

---

Follow these steps to add another iCloud account:
(I took the screenshots on an iPhone, but it is smiliar to your iPad)

1. Open “Settings” app on your homescreen

   [image]
2. Scroll down to “Mail, Contacts, Calendars” and tap on it

   [image]
3. You see a list of your accounts, scroll down and tap on “Add Account…”

   [image]
4. Choose “iCloud” and enter your data

   [image] [image]
5. Finished